# Solving a quintic equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the following equation in Mathematica:

```
Solve[(xc - x) == 1/(xr - (x + x0)^2) + 1/(xr - (x - x0)^2), x]
```

However, this yields

> ```
> {{x -> Root[-2 x0^2 - x0^4 xc + 2 xr + 2 x0^2 xc xr - xc xr^2 +  
>             (x0^4 - 2 x0^2 xr + xr^2) #1 + 
>             (-2 + 2 x0^2 xc + 2 xc xr) #1^2 + 
>             (-2 x0^2 - 2 xr) #1^3 - xc #1^4 + #1^5 &, 1]}, 
>  {x -> Root[-2 x0^2 - x0^4 xc + 2 xr + 2 x0^2 xc xr - xc xr^2 + 
>             (x0^4 - 2 x0^2 xr + xr^2) #1 + 
>             (-2 + 2 x0^2 xc + 2 xc xr) #1^2 + 
>             (-2 x0^2 - 2 xr) #1^3 - xc #1^4 + #1^5 &, 2]}, 
>  {x -> Root[-2 x0^2 - x0^4 xc + 2 xr + 2 x0^2 xc xr - xc xr^2 + 
>             (x0^4 - 2 x0^2 xr + xr^2) #1 + 
>             (-2 + 2 x0^2 xc + 2 xc xr) #1^2 + 
>             (-2 x0^2 - 2 xr) #1^3 - xc #1^4 + #1^5 &, 3]}, 
>  {x -> Root[-2 x0^2 - x0^4 xc + 2 xr + 2 x0^2 xc xr - xc xr^2 + 
>             (x0^4 - 2 x0^2 xr + xr^2) #1 + 
>             (-2 + 2 x0^2 xc + 2 xc xr) #1^2 + 
>             (-2 x0^2 - 2 xr) #1^3 - xc #1^4 + #1^5 &, 4]}, 
>  {x -> Root[-2 x0^2 - x0^4 xc + 2 xr + 2 x0^2 xc xr - xc xr^2 + 
>             (x0^4 - 2 x0^2 xr + xr^2) #1 + 
>             (-2 + 2 x0^2 xc + 2 xc xr) #1^2 + 
>             (-2 x0^2 - 2 xr) #1^3 - xc #1^4 + #1^5 &, 5]}}
> ```

If I remove the second fraction to the right of `==`, I get a regular three solutions for `x`. Is there a reason why the same thing doesn't happen when there are two fractions?

Comment: You have a [fifth-order polynomial equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function) and [there is no explicit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel–Ruffini_theorem) for its five solutions, so Mathematica gives you five [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects instead (best it can do).

Comment: oh! are they meaningful at all?

Comment: they are 'quasi' symbolic solutions, can be plotted and evaluated if you give values to x0,xr,xc.

Comment: @Roman `Root` objects are perfectly good explicit formulae, they just don't conform to Bronze Age notions of what an explicit formula is. They are often superior to formulae using radicals, as they tend to be simpler and more stable for purposes of numerical evaluation.

Comment: I think the software [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) is more suitable for solving such problems.

Comment: @JohnDoty sorry I meant ["closed-form expression"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression), not "explicit formula".

Comment: @Roman Since root isolation should be considered a standard operation in the 21st century, a `Root` of this sort is a closed form.